# PhantomJs : Screen capture of webpage loading data with $.POST fails

Tags: jquery, ajax, phantomjs, screen-capture

I was using PhantomJS to screen-capture my website.

It happens that on webpages that loads data with a jQuery Ajax call instead of requesting the given `remoteUrl`, PhantomJS requests the current webpage URL. This leads to re-including current page into current page for the given example:

*This code is executed on `$('document').ready()` on the webpage I'm trying to screen-capture:*

```
remoteUrl = $('#my-placeholder').data('api-url');

$.post(
    remoteUrl,
    {
        foo: bar
    },
    function(response){
        $('#my-placehoder').html(response);

        // instead of retrieving remoteUrl's content, 
        // result contains the same content as current page
    }
);
```

*Here's the code I use with PhantomJS:*

```
page.open(address, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        page.evaluate(function() {
            document.body.bgColor = 'white';
        });
        var arr = page.evaluate(function () {
            var pageWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
            var pageHeight = document.body.clientHeight;

            return [pageWidth, pageHeight];
        });

        page.viewportSize = { width: arr[0], height: arr[1] };
        page.render(output);
        phantom.exit();
    }
});
```

Is there some kind of limitations in PhantomJS about that? Or am I doing something wrong?

I've been looking for any clues that can helps me solving this issue, but Google remains unhelpful. Thanks!

Edit : Ok, after some test with error & console message binded, i got this

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(".is-clickable:not(.is-disabled)").clickEvent()')

  :9327
  :4
  :4
  :4
```

Wich don't occurs in a regular browser. It seems to be related to the none-availability of jQuery ?

Comment: This is a timing issue. Your capture happens before the script has finished loading the actual site content. Please add the PhantomJS code you use to capture the web page to your question.

Comment: Here is the phantomJS script :
https://gist.github.com/splio-aleroux/f3e7aaedaa279d084a00

Comment: But PhantomJS does execute the $.POST as the callback is executed and i can see the wrong data loaded in the screen-capture

Comment: Hint: You can always edit your question and fix mistakes or make additions. No need to put half of the question into a Gist.

Comment: What I don't understand: Phantom does what a regular browser would do. It does not behave "special" in any way. So when things get "re-included" (whatever that means) in Phantom for one URL, the same thing should happen in a real browser for that URL. Is that not the case?

Comment: No it's not. I a regular browser i do get the correct result, and moreover i've written some logs on the server side.
This don't happens while in PhantomJS (result and logs)

Comment: Have you registered the [`onConsoleMessage`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference-WebPage#webpage-onConsoleMessage) and [`onError`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference-WebPage#onerror) event handlers? Maybe there are errors. If bind is an issue, you will need a [shim](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522#issuecomment-39248521).

Comment: I've bound errors and console message, js error occurs that don't in regular browser